# RP3 doesn't load on HDMI - Mounting FUSE Control File System

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, fuses

I'd like to run my RP 3 on LCD 32". But when I try to run, loading is stopped after 9-10 seconds of starting up and the last line in the console is: 
"**Mounting FUSE Control File System...**"
After this communicate console is stopped.

Below, I show the screen from the LCD with this console log.

[image]

I'd like to add, that on my 3.5 GPIO it works properly.

Does somebody have any suggestion what could went wrong?
I would really appreciate if someone could help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems that Raspberry Pi 3 does not work with a monitor connected via HDMI port.

Answer (score -3):

```
cd LCD-show/
./LCD-hdmi
```

Then toggles the mode to lcd display:

```
./LCD35-show
```